# How does ar.yw estimate the variance

Tags: r

In R, how does the function ar.yw estimate the variance?  Specifically, where does the number "var.pred" come from?  It does not seem to come from the usual YW estimate of the variance, nor the sum of squared residuals divided by df (even though there is disagreement about what the df should be, none of the choices give an answer equivalent to var.pred).  And yes, I know that there are better methods than YW;  just trying to figure out what R is doing.

```
set.seed(82346)
temp <- arima.sim(n=10, list(ar = 0.5), sd=1)
fit <- ar(temp, method = "yule-walker", demean = FALSE, aic=FALSE, order.max=1)

##  R's estimate of the sigma squared
fit$var.pred
##  YW estimate
sum(temp^2)/10 - fit$ar*sum(temp[2:10]*temp[1:9])/10
##  YW if there was a mean
sum((temp-mean(temp))^2)/10 - fit$ar*sum((temp[2:10]-mean(temp))*(temp[1:9]-mean(temp)))/10
##  estimate based on residuals, different possible df.
sum(na.omit(fit$resid^2))/10
sum(na.omit(fit$resid^2))/9
sum(na.omit(fit$resid^2))/8
sum(na.omit(fit$resid^2))/7
```

Comment: A guess ... this is a function in the forecast package? You do realize that R packages are all open source?

Comment: @42, no, this is part of the "stats" package, i.e., the same package that gives us "lm" and all the other basic statistical functionality.  Thus one might assume, even though it is open source, that it would be doing something reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Need to read the code if it's not documented.

```
 ?ar.yw
```

Which says: "In ar.yw the variance matrix of the innovations is computed from the fitted coefficients and the autocovariance of x." If that is not enough explanation, then you need to look at the code:

```
methods(ar.yw)
#[1] ar.yw.default* ar.yw.mts*    
#see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

getAnywhere(ar.yw.default)
#  there are two cases that I see
x <- as.matrix(x)
nser <- ncol(x)
if (nser > 1L)  # .... not your situation
#....
else{
    r <- as.double(drop(xacf))
    z <- .Fortran(C_eureka, as.integer(order.max), r, r, 
        coefs = double(order.max^2), vars = double(order.max), 
        double(order.max))
    coefs <- matrix(z$coefs, order.max, order.max)
    partialacf <- array(diag(coefs), dim = c(order.max, 1L, 
        1L))
    var.pred <- c(r[1L], z$vars)
    #.......
    order <- if (aic) 
        (0L:order.max)[xaic == 0L]
    else order.max
    ar <- if (order) 
        coefs[order, seq_len(order)]
    else numeric()
    var.pred <- var.pred[order + 1L]
    var.pred <- var.pred * n.used/(n.used - (order + 1L))
```

So you now need to find the Fortran code for `C_eureka`. I think I'm finding it here: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/eureka.f  This is the code that aI think is returning the `var.pred` estimate. I'm not a time series guy and It's your responsibility to review this process for applicability to your problem.

```
      subroutine eureka (lr,r,g,f,var,a)
c
c      solves Toeplitz matrix equation toep(r)f=g(1+.)
c      by Levinson's algorithm
c      a is a workspace of size lr, the number
c      of equations
c
     snipped
c  estimate the innovations variance
        var(l) = var(l-1) * (1 - f(l,l)*f(l,l))
        if (l .eq. lr) return
        d = 0.0d0
        q = 0.0d0
        do 50 i = 1, l
          k = l-i+2
          d = d + a(i)*r(k)
          q = q + f(l,i)*r(k)
   50     continue
```

Comment: @IRFTM: Thanks for the excellent answer. One question--what is the `1L` argument? I can't find it in the documentation. I'm just trying to understand the `if (nser > 1L)` condition.

Comment: A capital "L" following a digit forces that value to be an integer. This and other useful information regarding forming numbers in complex, octal and hexadecimal representations as well as `NaN`can be found at `?NumericConstants`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So `if (nser > 1L)` is just checking whether the time series observations are scalars (nser = 1) or vectors (nser > 1)?

Comment: Not as I read it. It's checking to see if it's a multi-column matrix. Although maybe that's what you were saying?